# Blob creating function in javascript saving multiple files

Tags: javascript, html

Can someone explain to me how this piece of code works. Also, the output is not what I want. It saves 2 files instead of 1.
**Javascript**

```
function saveTextAsFile() {
     var textToWrite = document.getElementById('textArea').innerHTML;
     var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([ textToWrite ], { type: 'text/plain' });
     var fileNameToSaveAs = "file.txt";
   
     var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
     downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
     downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
     if (window.webkitURL != null) {
       downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
     } else {
       downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
       downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
       downloadLink.style.display = "none";
       document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
     }
   
     downloadLink.click();
   }
   
   var button = document.getElementById('save');
   button.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);
   
   function destroyClickedElement(event) {
     document.body.removeChild(event.target);
   }
```

**HTML**

```
    <button id="save" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save</button>
    <textarea id="textArea" class="Textarea" placeholder="Click to Type" cols="20"></textarea>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You code does NOT work:

1. textarea input values are read with `.value` not `.innerHTML`, you where getting no output so
   change:
   `var textToWrite = document.getElementById('textArea').innerHTML;`
   into
   `var textToWrite = document.getElementById('textArea').value;`
2. You get 2 files because you made 2 same events on same button that call same function, remove one of those:

   `<button id="save" onclick="saveTextAsFile()">Save</button>`
   here remove `onclick="saveTextAsFile()"` or remove this two lines:

   `var button = document.getElementById('save');`

   `button.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);`

This will fix your errors, and as far how whole code works, this is not code review site, for that visit https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ or google each command and read its definitions.

Comment: When I tried removing `var button = document.getElementById('save');`

`button.addEventListener('click', saveTextAsFile);`it still saved 2 files. But other than that, when I tried removing `onclick="saveTextAsFile()"` it worked fine. Thanks

Comment: @SomeRandomUser101_ Not possible with code you presented.